# Find normal to an hypersurface in parametric form not taking a cross product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I know that in 3 dimensions, you can calculate a normal vector of an hypersurface given parametrically like $r = r(x, y, z)$ with $x = x(u, v)$; $y = y(u,v)$; $z = z(u, v)$ just by the equation

$$\vec{n} = \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|}$$

I'm wondering how to generalize this to bigger dimensions where you can't take a cross product because it is not defined. Imagine 4 dimensions, where $r = r(x, y, z, t)$ with $x = x(u, v, w)$; $y = y(u, v, w)$; $z = z(u, v, w)$; $t = (u, v, w)$

(I know that if I had $F(x, y, z, t) = 0$ the normal would be the gradient).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an anlog of the cross product in higher dimensions, but it takes $n-1$ entries in dimension $n$ (which is exactly what you need). This is most easilz defined as follows. Take $n-1$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ and insert them into the natural volume form (which you can write as $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$). The result is a linear functional on $\mathbb R^n$ that you can then convert into a vector using the inner product. Otherwise put, you can characterize this map by $\langle \times(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}),v)=det(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v)$. Inserting the standard basis vectors for $v$, you get a formula for the components of $\times(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})$ (which is not a standard notation) via determinants of matrices obtained by removing one line from the $n\times (n-1)$-matrix $(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})$, so this generalizes one of the standard formulae for the cross product.

Comment: Thanks. Then basically the normal would be something like $r_u \times r_v \times r_w$ with the cross product defined like a box here (link from amd's comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra), with the important caveat that vector basis is the last row. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct. I don't find the conventions in the Wikipedia article well chosen, since usually I would represent vectors as columns and not as rows. But this leads to the same result, since the determinant is not changed when transposing a matrix.